# Python loop in emails body

Tags: python, email, smtp

I have this html email body and trying to put a loop to structure a list nicely.

```
item = (["<li>{}</li>".format(x) for x in list])
html = """\
<html>
  <body>
    <p>hi:<br>
       <br>
       """ +  str(item) +"""
    </p>
  </body>
</html>
"""
```

The list:

```
['mango', 'peach', 'banana', 'apple']
```

Desired result in email:

```
mango

peach

banana

apple
```

Current result:

```
["

'
mango
', '
peach
', '
banana
', '
apple']

"]
```

Comment: Ok, cool. What's the problem with the code? See also [ask].

Comment: @Robert my bad, just updated entire question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use [str.join](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.join) instead of casting to a string:

```py
' '.join(item)
```